# Tryiing to add swiping navigation tabs in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

i am following this guide to create a swipe navigation tabs using fragments but it doesnt work as the tabListener from teh example doesnt specify how to set it in the given example.

i know you can manually set it by creating tab objects manually using actionBar.addTab() but because i am using a ViewPager and PageAdaper, how do i add the tabs automatically from the amount of items in the PageAdaper?

Here is my Page Adapter code:

```
public class AppPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragmentsList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public AppPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> list) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentsList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return "fragment " + position;
    }
```

Here is Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private List<Fragment> fragmentsList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //setup fragments
        fragmentsList.add(new AppListFragment());
        fragmentsList.add(new AppListFragment());
        fragmentsList.add(new AppListFragment());
        fragmentsList.add(new AppListFragment());


        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //set Adapter and viewPager objects
        AppPageAdapter pageAdapter = new AppPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentsList);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        setupActionBarTabs();

//        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//        ft.add(R.id.mainLayout, new AppListFragment());
//        ft.commit();
    }

    private void setupActionBarTabs() {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

            }
        };



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

here is the example i am following:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

I get this error when executing teh current code base:

```
ava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImpl.java:363)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImplICS.java:124)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
            at com.example.myapplication.app.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:50)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:567)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2015)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygo
```